# GetItems Ignores ViewFields in Query

Tags: spquery, viewfields

I have created the following method to fetch list items from a list. The method does return the right items, but no matter what I provide in the `viewFields` parameter, it always returns all fields.

```
public SPListItemCollection GetListItems(SPWeb web, string listTitle, Dictionary<string, string> queryParams, params string[] viewFields)
{
  var query = new SPQuery();

  //queryString is returning appropriate items
  var queryString = this.CreateQueryString(true, queryParams);
  query.Query = queryString;

  var queryViewFields = string.Empty;
  foreach (string viewField in viewFields)
  {
    var field = web.Fields[viewField];
    var queryViewField = string.Format("<FieldRef Name='{0}' />", field.InternalName);

    queryViewFields += queryViewField;
  }

  // To me, this queryViewFields also seems to be fine
  query.ViewFields = queryViewFields;

 // If no view fields are specified, return all fields
  query.ViewFieldsOnly = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryViewFields); 

  var list = web.Lists[listTitle];
  var items = list.GetItems(query);

  return items;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What are you passing in **params string[] viewFields** ?

Comment: I am passing display names of the fields.

Comment: Is that helps you?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help. There is a line `var field = web.Fields[viewField];` that gets the field from the display name parameter, and the next line `var queryViewField = string.Format("<FieldRef Name='{0}' />", field.InternalName);` that explicitly uses internal name.

Answer (score 1):

**For Server side code**

You just need to change the code as mentioned below & try it again

```
public SPListItemCollection GetListItems(SPWeb web, string listTitle, Dictionary<string, string> queryParams, params string[] viewFields)
{
  SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

  //queryString is returning appropriate items
  var queryString = this.CreateQueryString(true, queryParams);
  query.Query = queryString;

  string queryViewFields = string.Empty;
  foreach (string viewField in viewFields)
  {
    string field = web.Fields[viewField];
    string queryViewField = string.Format("<FieldRef Name='{0}' />", field.InternalName);

    queryViewFields += queryViewField;
  }

  // To me, this queryViewFields also seems to be fine
  query.ViewFields = queryViewFields;

 // If no view fields are specified, return all fields
  query.ViewFieldsOnly = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryViewFields); 

  SPList list = web.Lists[listTitle];
  SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

  return items;
}
```

**If you are using client-object model than please check below solution**

In client object model only specifying ViewFields is not enough. You need to combine it with a linq statement like this:

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Where><Eq>.<FieldRef Name='Country' /><Value Type='Text'>Belgium</Value></Eq></Where></View>";
ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItems,
  items => items.Include(
  item => item.Id,
  item => item.DisplayName,
  item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

It may work for you..

Comment: Hi Hardik, I am using server side code. I don't see that replacing a boolean logic with a boolean value makes any difference.

Comment: Can you remove that line & try it?

Comment: Is the solutions works for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Please try updated code in above answer.

Comment: I tried, and it doesn't work. Your solution proposal does not resolve anything.

Comment: I need to check now that what you are passing in **Dictionary<string, string> queryParams** and **params string[] viewFields**. Than after i can confirm it.